# Local extrema of a function subject to an inequality

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Preparing for my exams I came across a problem I don't know how to solve :

> Find the extremums of given function on domain $D$ and check if the function reaches it : $$f(x, y, z) = x + y + z$$ where $D = \left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R} : x^2+y^2\leq z\ \leq 1 \right\}$

Now, I know how to solve ones with EQUALITY instead of INEQUALITY (using Langranges Multipliers), how should I approach this one?

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz (or direct computation) gives

$$
(x+y)^2 \leq 2(x^2+y^2),
$$

so

$$
f(x,y,z) =x+y+z \leq \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}+z \leq \sqrt{2z}+z \leq \sqrt{2}+1
$$

The inequality becomes an equality when all the intermediate inequalities
are equalities. So the maximum is $1+\sqrt{2}$, attained at exactly one point, 
$(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},1)$.

On the other hand,

$$
f(x,y,z) =x+y+z \geq -\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}+z \geq z-\sqrt{2z}
= t^2-\sqrt{2}t=(t-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2-\frac{1}{2} \geq
(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2-\frac{1}{2}=1-\sqrt{2}
$$

The inequality becomes an equality when all the intermediate inequalities
are equalities. Thus the minimum is $1-\sqrt{2}$, attained at exactly one point, 
$(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},1)$.

Answer (score 0):

It should be kept in mind what the Lagrange-multiplier method does for us:  it provides the location of the point(s) of tangency between a "constraint surface" and a "level surface" for a function; this occurs where the normal vector at a point on the constraint surface is parallel (or anti-parallel) to the normal vector at the same point on the level surface.  So the method cannot by itself given us the extremal values of a function over a region defined by inequalities, but only provides information for "surfaces" specified by equations.

We must put that method together with our techniques for locating critical points in order to find extremal values for a function on a region.  In this problem, part of this is made simple because the function $ \ f(x, \ y, \ z) \ = \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ $ has *all* of its first partial derivatives being $ \ 1 \ \ne \ 0 \ $ , so the function has *no* critical points.

The inequality $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ \le \ z \ \le \ 1 \ $ describes the region in $ \ \mathbb{R}^3  \ $ which is on or above the paraboloid $ \ z \ = \  x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ $ **and** on or below the plane $ \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ .  As we have already noted, the interior of this region contains no critical points of the function, so no extremal values occur within it.

We can now deal with the two surfaces in turn.  The paraboloid constraint is described by $ \ g(x, \ y, \ z) \ = \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ - \ z \ $ , so the Lagrange equations will be

$$ \nabla f \ = \ \lambda \  \nabla g \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 1 \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 2x \ \ , \ \ 1 \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 2y \ \ , \ \ 1 \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ (-1) $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{1}{2x} \ = \ \frac{1}{2y} \ = \ -1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ y \ = \ -\frac{1}{2} \ \ . $$

Inserting this result into the equation of the paraboloid gives $ \ z \ = \ \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \ + \ \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ .  Since this value for $ \ z \ $ *is* less than 1 , it gives us the tangent point $ \ \left( -\frac{1}{2}, \ -\frac{1}{2}, \ \frac{1}{2} \right) \ $ between the paraboloid and the plane $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ = \ -\frac{1}{2} \ $ .  So we have an extremal value for $ \ f(x, \ y, \ z) \ $ on the paraboloid surface.

[image]

*views of the bounded paraboloid region and the level surface $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ = \ -\frac{1}{2} \ $ ; the tilted plane is shifted very slightly in this plot to make the tangent point visible*

We also need to look at the surface in the plane $ \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ within the paraboloid, which is a circle of radius 1 centered on the $ \ z-$ axis (specifically, at the point $ \ ( 0, \ 0, \ 1) \ $ ) .  Again, there will be no critical points in the disk, so we will want to look at extrema on the circumference of the circle.  Here, we use the constraint function $ \ h(x, \ y) \ = \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ - \ 1 \ $ , together with $ \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ .  The Lagrange equations are

$$ \nabla f \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ \nabla h \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 1 \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 2x \ \ , \ \ 1 \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 2y $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{1}{2x} \ = \ \frac{1}{2y} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ y \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x^2 \ = \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  x \ = \ y \ = \ \pm \ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ \ . $$

We thus have two values of our function to examine.  For $ \ f \left( -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \ -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \ 1 \right) \ = \ 1 \ - \ \sqrt{2} \ $ , the plane $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ = \ 1 \ - \ \sqrt{2} \ $ indeed touches the circle in the $ \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ plane at a single point, but it also passes through the interior of the bounded region.  So this value of the function is *not* minimal over the entire specified region.

[image]

*an "overhead" view of the paraboloid region, showing where the level surface $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ = \ 1 \ - \ \sqrt{2} \ $ meets the plane $ \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ ; the level surface is shifted slightly to make the tangent point evident*

On the other hand, the level surface  $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ = \ 1 \ + \ \sqrt{2} \ $ touches the circle in the $ \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ plane at $ \ \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \ 1 \right) $ , without meeting the paraboloid surface at all.

[image]

Hence, for the region bounded by the given inequality, the maximal value of $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ $ is $ \ 1 \ + \ \sqrt{2} \ $ and the minimal value is $ \ -\frac{1}{2} \ $ .